# Analysis of a chess position?

Tags: opening

Is there a site I can go to or a software which I can use which will help me to analyse a chess position?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I analyze my game after playing?](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-do-i-analyze-my-game-after-playing)

Comment: That is a very interesting and relevant question, but I think it already has been asked and answered, maybe in a more general way.

Comment: You can post your game here for an analysis, I believe community will be more than glad to help you. As for software recommendation, you can use any strong engine for analysis...

Comment: This is my game 1.d4 e6
                2.d5 Nf6
                3.c4                                            I have not seen this play before and do not know how best to respond.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by 'analyse'. Any chess engine with a GUI will allow you to input a position and get sample lines from the engine, while letting you try out variations. Online services that allow this include http://lichess.org (you'd have to upload a game's PGN there first) or http://analysis.cpuchess.com/.

If by 'analyse' you mean study and learn from the nuances of a position, then the short answer is no - while a GUI might provide a way of easily resetting the board to certain states, it can't do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a few analysis tools. See which works best for you:

1. lichess.org/analysis
2. decodechess.com
3. chess.com/analysis-board-editor